# What is the mathematical mystery here?

Tags: radicals

I know that, $$\sqrt{25}=5≠-5$$

But, in quadratic equation we write $$(2ax+b)^2=b^2-4ac$$

> $$(2ax+b)=±\sqrt{b^2-4ac}$$

Why?? We must *write $±$, and What is the mathematical mystery here?*

Comment: From $(-3)^2=9$ you cannot conclude that $(-3)=3$.

Comment: $5^2$ and $(-5)^2$ both equal $25$. Similarly, $x^2 = (-x)^2$. Thus, when applying $\sqrt{}$ to both sides of an equation you need to consider both the positive and negative roots.

Comment: No mystery, the solutions of $y^2=25$ are $y=\pm 5.$

Comment: I think I'm not satisfied..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In $\mathbb{R}$ there are two numbers $x$ such that $x^2=a$ (for $a>0$), and these two numbers have opposite sign, but, by definition, the symbol $\sqrt{a}$ indicates only the positive one of such two numbers, so, if we want indicate expliciltly all the two we must write $ x= \pm \sqrt{a}$.

Comment: $\sqrt{25 }=-5$ is it true?

Comment: No, $\sqrt{25}$ is, by definition, the **positive** number $x$ such that $x^2=25$, so it is  $5$. It is calle also the principla square root: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root

Comment: Why?? ı am sorry, because I dont understand realy.. $-5$ is not a real root of $\sqrt{25}$ ??

Comment: Yes, $-5$ is a real square root of $25$ but it is not the **principal** (that is  positive) square root. so it is $-5=-\sqrt{25}$

Comment: What you are telling us is that you do not understand what $\sqrt{x}$ means.  You have already been told that $\sqrt{x}$ is **defined** as "the positive number whose square is x".  -5 is not a root of $\sqrt{25}$ because it is not positive.  Again, there are **two** solutions to $x^2= a$.  One of them is $\sqrt{a}$, the other is $-\sqrt{a}$.

Comment: @Emilio Novati Perfect!! Now I understand!!!

Comment: İn all calculus we must take only positive root. Do I u dersrand true?

Comment: The symbol $\sqrt{a}$ idicates only the positive root of $a$, so if we want the negative one we have to write $-\sqrt{a}$  and, if we want both the roots we write $\pm \sqrt{a}$.

Comment: @Emilio Novati ı underatood fully. thank you so much!!!

Comment: You are welcome!  And don't forget to accept if you like :)

Comment: @Emilio Novati  :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to be careful as if we treat $\sqrt{x}$ as a function then we conventionally assume the value is $\ge0$ (there can't be two values as it wouldn't be a function at all), however $\sqrt{x}$ (or in general e.g. $\sqrt[n]{x}$ in $\mathbb{C}$) may denote the whole **set** of numbers such that each of them squared (raised to the $n$th power respectively) equals $x$, then it is obviously not a function.